# How to check whether the user clicks the new / edit TreeListCommandColumn in DevExpress ASPxTreeList

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, devexpress

I want to validate in the server side based on the condition whether the user clicks the New / Edit TreeListCommandColumn

I searched the aspxtreelist documentation but I am not able to find what I need.

How to check whether the user clicks the new / edit TreeListCommandColumn in DevExpress ASPxTreeList?

Comment: Why don't you contact DX guys directly?

Comment: I will get quick response and also the exact solution for my requirement from `Stack Overflow` compared to any other site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ASPxTreeList.IsNewNodeEditing](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTreeListASPxTreeList_IsNewNodeEditingtopic) property. Property should be true when user clicks New.

Comment: It is working fine as expected. Thanks.